# updating column with value from another column in postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a postgres table which has 2 columns

username and email
I have hundreds of rows in the table such as

```
username | email
username1 | test@abc.com
username2 | test@abc.com
username3 | test@abc.com
username4 | test@abc.com
```

The way this was setup all emails are the same, and now I need to make them unique. I am trying to update the email column to be like this

```
username | email
username1 | username1_test@abc.com
username2 | username2_test@abc.com
username3 | username3_test@abc.com
username4 | username4_test@abc.com
```

basically copy over the value from the username column and add it to the email column.
I tried using the coalesce function but that will replace the value completely and not update it.

Please can you help me understand how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An update with basic concatenation should work here:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET email = username || '_' || email;
```

Comment: Note the the concatenation operator || will return null in case one of the fields username or email is null. 
If you want to replace null values with empty strings use the concat function instead:
 
SET email = concat(username, '_', email).